# $\Bbb R^n$ vector valued function continuous with arbitrary metric

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

**Theorem 4.10 (Baby Rudin)** Let $f_1,\dots,f_k$ be real functions on a metric space $X$ and let **f** be the mapping of $X$ onto $\Bbb R^k$ by $$\textbf{f}(x)=(f_1(x),\dots,f(k(x))\qquad (x\in X)$$

then **f** is continuous if and only if each of the functions $f_1,\dots, f_k$ is continuous.

The proof in Rudin says the solution follows from the inequalities

$$|f_j(x)-f)j(y)|\leq|\textbf{f}(x)-\textbf{f}(y)|=\{\sum_{i=1}^k|f_i(x)-f_i(y)|\}^\frac{1}{2}$$

However this depends on the choice of metric on $\Bbb R^k$. Is there any way to prove this claim that doesn't depend on the metric put on $\Bbb R^k$?

Comment: How is your question related to [tag:complex-analysis]?

Comment: It would have to be a metric that works nicely within $\mathbb{R}$'s structure. For instance, what if someone were to define a metric $d$ where $d(0, 1) >> d(0, 2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on the metric on $\mathbb R$ which gives a product metric on the product $\mathbb R^k.$ For a counterexample when you're not using the product metric space, use $\mathbb R$ with the standard metric and $\mathbb R^k$ with the discrete metric. The following is the correct generalization of the theorem: Let $X,Y$ be topological (or metric) spaces and let $f:X\to Y^k$ be a map given by $f(x)=(f_1(x),\ldots,f_k(x)).$ Then $f$ is continuous if and only if each $f_i$ is continuous.

If $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces with metrics $d_X$ and $d_Y$ respectively, then the proof indeed comes from the inequality $$d_Y(f_j(x)-f_j(y))\le \left[\sum_{i=1}^k d_Y(f_i(x),f_i(y))^2\right]^{1/2}$$ for $x,y\in X$ along with the fact that *the product metric* on $Y^k$ is given by $d_{Y^k}(x,y)=\left[\sum_{i=1}^k d_Y(x,y)^2\right]^{1/2}.$ For topological spaces in general the proof is just as short.